# Configure Httpd for SSL

Tags: apache, ssl, https, httpd.conf

I'm writing this after trying for almost 4hrs and endless googling.

After adding the 433 virtual port in my httpd.config file I get this error
**"Invalid command 'SSLEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration"**

This is my addition to the httpd.config

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
SSLEngine on                                                                
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2                                                      
SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM                

SSLCertificateFile /path/unified.crt                           
SSLCertificateKeyFile /path/my-private-decrypted.key                        
SSLCertificateChainFile /path/sub.class1.server.sh2.ca.pem 
ServerAdmin root@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/html
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>

ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
<Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

# Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
# alert, emerg.
LogLevel warn

CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>
```

I'm totally confused ! Please Anyone Help out ! Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Finally , fixed it !

To enable ssl in httpd run :

```
sudo yum install mod24_ssl
```

Comment: No package mod24_ssl available.
Error: Nothing to do